# Xamarin forms listview without caching strategy after refreshing the list showing empty cells at the top

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project in Xamarin.Forms which contains a listView bound to a List.

The listView contains cells, each with a label and an image. I have one toolbar item: refresh. the refresh updates the list with the new items.

I am not using CachingStrategy.

The interesting part is: refresh toolbar item, the upper part of the listView (which is visible on-screen) is not refresh BUT when I scroll down the listView, the newly generated cells and old cells are visible.

How can I refresh the list without displaying empty cells?

Comment: You might wanna add your code, otherwise, all the answers you get will be plain speculation

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Use **ObservableCollection** instead of **List**

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> MyItemsSource { get; set; }
```

ObservableCollection is a generic dynamic data collection that uses an interface "INotifyCollectionChanged" to provide notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole collection is refreshed.

If your project still does not work .You can post your code or share a sample ,which will help us to find out the cause .